# How to update Django HttpRequest body in Middleware

Tags: python, django, httprequest, middleware

I have a PUT request and I want to update the values of few of the params in my middleware. I know there is no way to directly access the PUT params, so I'm accessing them via `request.body`.

Once these values have been updated, I need to pass this `request` onto the view. However, if I try to do:

```
request.body = new_content
```

in my middleware, I get:

```
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Is there any way to update these params in the middleware and pass them on?

Answer (score 15):

[`request.body`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L204) is defined as a `property` in [`HttpRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest) class.

This is code how `body` property looks like:

```
@property
def body(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_body'):
        if self._read_started:
            raise RawPostDataException("You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream")
        try:
            self._body = self.read()
        except IOError as e:
            six.reraise(UnreadablePostError, UnreadablePostError(*e.args), sys.exc_info()[2])
        self._stream = BytesIO(self._body)
    return self._body
```

The aproach that I will use there is to modify `_body` attribute in the [`process_request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_request) method. The return value here is `None`, because I want that Django continue processing that request through middleware until to the appropriate view.

```
class MidddlewareWithHttpPutRequest:
    def process_request(self, request):
        data = getattr(request, '_body', request.body)
        request._body = data + '&dummy_param=1'
        # if you call request.body here you will see that new parameter is added
        return None
```

Comment: To add a note to this: request.body will call request.read() which reads from a file-like buffer `request._stream`. I needed to "refill" this buffer as well (Django Rest Framework reads from this buffer). You can do so by `request._stream = BytesIO(body_contents)`